# How can I get likert element title and descriptions of the questions in webform submission handler?

Tags: webforms

How can I get likert element title and descriptions of the questions in custom webform submission handler? getData() gives only questions and answers, is there another method?

Webform 8.x-5.2

Comment: Why is it downvoted again? Last time I asked what's the best way and it was downvoted as being too subjective. This time I'm asking how it can be done at all and it is still being downvoted! I suspect by the same people because the count is exactly the same.

I have a problem, I'm asking for solution. The question is relevant to this site, to drupal, to webform. If not then please explain why exactly and how exactly should I ask it so that it would be ok with you.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question but it might be a lack of effort in trying to find an answer yourself. In your submitForm function you can see theres several other variables passed in. Have you tried looking in those to see what's available? As you'll probably find what you're after in the $form variable which contains the form array with all descriptions/titles and whatever else. Perhaps take a look in there and if you have a specific question based off of that people might be able to help

Comment: -1 what is "likert"?

Comment: I've looked at WebformSubmissionInterface.php and its methods. The only way I see is to load the whole webform object and try to get them from there. I'm not very familiar with object oriented php and I couldn't figure out how exactly to do that. This data is protected so it's not very simple.

Comment: No Sssweat - you don't understand the question and therefore downvoted it? That's not cool. I assure you that those who know the answer to this question have no problem understanding it.

Comment: @user93158 I shouldn't have to resort to google to understand your question. Therefore, your question is unclear. You can link to stuff you know.

Comment: No Sssweat - likert element is a webform element type. If you don't know what it is then you don't know the answer to the question as well which means that this question is not for you.

Comment: @user93158 just because I don't know the answer in this instant, does not mean I cannot solve it. If you want someone to help you, you make it as easy as possible for them to understand. BTW you can also put a screen shot you know... But if you don't want to put any effort towards your question then good luck.

Comment: @No Sssweat screenshot of what? If you do know how webform works then you also know what objects and methods are available in wiriting a submission handler. It doesn't matter at all what code I have in there.

This is the very first time I have asked a question in StackExchange. I have always searched for answers myself as I did this time. So far I have received zero constructive suggestions, only scolding and downvoting. Great welcome indeed. Reminds me the culture some usenet groups used to have in the 90s...

Comment: @user93158 with your attitude, feel lucky that I bothered to answer your question. I hope this teaches you to not underestimate anyone here! Check your ego at the door next time and stay humble. See the screenshot I provided in my answer, had you provided that from the beginning that would've made a huge difference towards understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the title & description with:

```
$webform_submission->getWebform()->getElementsDecoded()['key_name']['#questions']['question value'];

$webform_submission->getWebform()->getElementsDecoded()['key_name']['#answers']['answer value'];
```

For Example:

[image]

```
$webform_submission->getWebform()->getElementsDecoded()['test']['#questions']
```

Will give:

[image]

Notice that the title & description are together. If you want them separate just [explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) them

```
  $question_text_desc = $webform_submission->getWebform()->getElementsDecoded()['test']['#questions']['Band Name'];
  $question_array = explode(" -- ", $question_text_desc);
  $question_text = $question_array[0];
  $question_desc = $question_array[1];
```

Obviously the above example is hard coded, in reality you'll prob want to do a loop

```
$questions = $webform_submission->getWebform()->getElementsDecoded()['test']['#questions'];
$question_info = [];
foreach ($questions as $question_value => $question_text_desc) {
  $question_array = explode(" -- ", $question_text_desc);
  $question_info[]['text'] = $question_array[0];
  $question_info[]['desc'] = $question_array[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sssweat!